# QuickBlox currentSession is always null

Tags: android, quickblox

I am trying to implement QuickBlox voice calling in my App, following the instruction from instruction from [Prepare your application for Android](https://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-webrtc-android#Prepare_your_application_for_Android_SDK) 
[image: AppFiles]
[image: gradle_Image]

the error message: 
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.quickblox.videochat.webrtc.QBRTCSession.addSessionCallbacksListener(com.quickblox.videochat.webrtc.callbacks.QBRTCSessionConnectionCallbacks)' on a null object reference

```
  QBChatService.getInstance().getVideoChatWebRTCSignalingManager()
            .addSignalingManagerListener(new QBVideoChatSignalingManagerListener() {
                @Override
                public void signalingCreated(QBSignaling qbSignaling, boolean createdLocally) {
                    if (!createdLocally) {
                        QBRTCClient.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addSignaling((QBWebRTCSignaling) qbSignaling);
                    }
                }
            });
    WebRtcSessionManager.getInstance(this).getCurrentSession().addSessionCallbacksListener(this);
    WebRtcSessionManager.getInstance(this).getCurrentSession().addVideoTrackCallbacksListener(this);
    QBRTCClient.getInstance(this).addSessionCallbacksListener(this);
    QBRTCClient.getInstance(this).prepareToProcessCalls();
```

Comment: I am logged in to chat but i am still not able to add signalling.  isCreatedLocally always returning null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before starting call you must be logged in chat QBChatService.getInstance().login(). So, check login to the chat.

Comment: Thank you. It helps